# Effective and cheap way of hosting images

Tags: images, cdn, vps

I'm making a website that uses mostly images, they take up to 150gb disk space. My VPS is only 40GB SSD and I'm looking for a way to host images elsewhere. How can I achieve that? What are the ways - should I just buy a larger disk, use some sort of CDN? I'm a complete noob at those things, so please help me out.

Comment: Object storage(Like Amazon S3 and Google cloud storage) and CDN both are good way to host large number of images. GCS and S3 also serve images very fast if user requesting file from the same region on which the bucket is located. I suggest first go with object storage, if you think you can invest more then go for CDN. CDN is costly because they copied your images on different pop server and that pop server are located very closely to users, hence fast speed + lower latency to download any objects. Your question will going to close because it is too broad + you're asking for recommended service

Comment: @Goyllo answer?